# Back button support on Visual Force page for salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have an href on a visual force page that takes the user back to the previous page using javascript. It works fine on desktop browsers, but does not work on the mobile site or the salesforce 1 app. What can be done to have support across all devices?

This is the current set up

```
<a href="history.back();" onclick="history.back();">Back To Quote</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [Managing Navigation Section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_navigation.htm) of the [Salesforce1 Mobile App Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/), particularly [Navigation with the sforce.one Object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm).

You'll need to add Javascript to your page to determine if you're in Salesforce1 which then sets the navigation link accordingly if it returns true because the back button works differently in Salesforce1 than in the standard platform from a regular browser. Your code will need to be adjusted to take this into account. Within SF1 you can't directly manipulate the browser URL using `window.location.href` and similar callouts as this doesn't work well with the Salesforce1 navigation management system.